# TD with rowspan has more height than content (nested table): 1px diff in border placement of nested tables mimic the same row height of outer table

Tags: html, css, html-table

i have a outer table with a fixed row height (in this example 24px).
i want to nest a table to add some content but also want to mimic the row heights and borders inside.
But there is a 1px difference as you can see here:

[image]

I cannot explain this, but have the feeling that is has something to do with the rowspan and maybe the nested table with flexboxes.

Question:
I wonder that the innerTable has a expected height of 72px, but the parent td.itemblock has a height of 72.8px.
Can someone tell me the reason for this difference? And is there some setting to prevent this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
  height: 24px;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firstColumn {
  width: 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.small {
  width: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 24px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.innerTable td {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.itemCell {
  position: relative;
}

.innerTable td.blockCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="outerTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="itemBlock">

        <table class="innerTable">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="itemCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">some content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="blockCell"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="itemCell blockCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">other content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Update:

- Its confirmed to happen in Mac Chrome and Safari, probably also in other browsers (check the result with Run Code Snippet)
- it happens regardless if the browser zoom in/out is used or not.

With the proposals i was able to assemble this, which looks like it is working. The changes are:

- use box-shadows instead of border-bottom
- set inner table height
- set height of Item div to calc(100% - 0.75px)

Though it seems i have a "hacky" solution, still i dont have an explanation for this! Any html table experts?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
  height: 24px;
}

td {
  box-shadow: 3px -3.5px 0px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firstColumn {
  width: 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.small {
  width: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.innerTable td {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 72px;
}

.itemCell {}

.item {
  height: calc(100% - 0.75px);
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.innerTable td.blockCell {
  box-shadow: 3px -3.5px 0px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) inset;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="outerTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="itemBlock">

        <table class="innerTable">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="itemCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">some content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="blockCell"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="itemCell blockCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">other content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Is there a chance that you have your browser window zoomed in? In some cases it indicates different dimensions that they are initially. On my system, when the browser is at normal zoom, it indicates 73px but when zooming in I can see various sizes, 72.688px, 72,585px, etc

Comment: @scooterlord the difference is there whether zoomed or not.

Comment: with the updated "solution" still i see after zoom in that the div item is not spanning the full height, but i could live with this. ;(

Comment: Did you reset all margins, paddings, outlines etc? see HTML reset. Just to be sure we are not chasing ghosts

Comment: @RobAu i added the HTML reset both to the original as well as to the hacky solution snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Cause

Using `box-sizing:border-box` is relevant only for the parent cell who has the border - but the nested table doesn't care about it's parent's border, only about its own.

In a plain table the border of the cells is part of the cell and thus considered in the computation of the cell heights:

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

In the case of a nested table, the border belongs to the cell that contains the table, and thus is not available for computing the height of the cell:

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

#### 2. Solution

Finding the solution is harder than determining the cause.

My idea is to

```
    .innerTable{
```

1. use the margin to stretch the inner table to cover the border of the containing cell:

```
      margin-top: -1px;
      margin-bottom: -1px;
```

2. then draw the border on the inner table so it looks again like the containing cell had a border:

```
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Setting only `margin-bottom` (or even worse, setting `margin-bottom:-2px`) doesn't help - `border-collapse: collapse;` means that two cells share their border, but it doesn't change that they end up having borders on both sides, so the size of both borders needs to be counted.

```css
.innerTable{
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
  height: 24px;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firstColumn {
  width: 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.small {
  width: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 24px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.innerTable td {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.itemCell {
  position: relative;
}

.innerTable td.blockCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="outerTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="itemBlock">

        <table class="innerTable">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="itemCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">some content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="blockCell"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="itemCell blockCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">other content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Many thanks - for the explanation and also your solution. Looks good.

Answer (score 4):

```css
   

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

tr {
  height: 24px;
}



td {

 box-shadow: 3px -3.5px 0px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firstColumn {
  width: 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.small {
  width: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 24px;
}

.innerTable td {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}
td.itemCell {
    background: lightblue;
}
.itemCell {
  position: relative;
}

.innerTable td.blockCell {
box-shadow: 3px -3.5px 0px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="outerTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="itemBlock">

        <table class="innerTable">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="itemCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">some content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="blockCell"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="itemCell blockCell">
             <div class="item">
                <div class="title">other content</div>
             </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: result looks good, but in my real example the item-div contains arbitrary content with its own layout, therefore i think this might be a hint, that it is related to the flexbox, which is removed here.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer and gives a solution for the cell border question. Content in table cells can have side effects, good to know.

Answer (score 3):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

tr {
  height: 24px;
}



td {

 box-shadow: 3px -3.5px 0px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firstColumn {
  width: 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.small {
  width: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 24px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.innerTable td {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.itemCell {
  position: relative;
}

.innerTable td.blockCell {
box-shadow: 3px -3.5px 0px -3px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="outerTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="itemBlock">

        <table class="innerTable">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="itemCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">some content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="blockCell"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="itemCell blockCell">
             <div class="item">
                <div class="title">other content</div>
             </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the steps and background of the proposal? And is there an answer to my question (see above)?

Comment: There is an issue introduced with margin-bottom: 2px
Due to that the conten of the item-div is not filling the space anylonger. If margin-bottom:1px is used that there is a strange alpha-blended overlap with the next bottom border.

Comment: Can you check now, I have changed margin-bottom to 1px.

Comment: It looks better, but if you zoom in you will still see that the lightblue background is not filling the complete height.

Comment: Do you have an explanation, because at least the parent td.itemblock has now the correct height?

Comment: yes, I have replaced the border-bottom with box-shadow & it draws a line above the td.

Comment: the question is: Can someone tell me the reason for this difference?

Comment: Can you confirm if this issue only happens in Chrome and after Zooming the browser? Did you try other browsers?

Comment: @Karthik: it happens in chrome, whether zoomed or not. I also run it in Safari to the same result. You can check yourself if you Run Code Snippet with other browsers.

Answer (score -2):

As I have already mentioned as a comment, first of all ensure that the browser isn't zoomed-in so that you have accurate results.

If you carefully notice the rows where all cells are single, you see that each table cell has a total height of **24px - 23px of the cell plus 1px** of the the border.

The table cells next to the table-block, have a height of 24.333px, this is due to the fact that there are 2px missing from the borders.

So, the total height of the cell that holds the table item should be `24*3=72px+1px` border, giving a total of 73px. Now divide this by 3 (the rowspan) and you can see that each table cell next to the merged one equal to `24.333px` `(73/3)`. This is simply the outcome of the observation.

The thing with tables it that they sometimes render in an arbitrary way, so you can't really predict the rendered result. I am sure there is a way to prevent it, in this particular example I would set `margin-bottom:-1px` to the `table.innertable`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

tr {
  height: 24px;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firstColumn {
  width: 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

td.small {
  width: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 24px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}

.innerTable td {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.itemCell {
  position: relative;
}

.innerTable td.blockCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
table.innerTable {
  margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="outerTable">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="itemBlock">

        <table class="innerTable">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" class="itemCell">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="title">some content</div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="blockCell"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="itemCell blockCell">
             <div class="item">
                <div class="title">other content</div>
             </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="firstColumn">2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="small"></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as mentioned, zoom doesnt change the behavior (only values).
Due to box-sizing: border-box; it should not make any difference if there is a border or not as it should count to the fixed row height, imo.
In your example the issue is still present, there are even 2 more issues, also the bottom of the "other content" is pushed down by one pixel and the "some content" is overlapping the grid and shows not bottom border anymore.

Comment: @HilmarDemant it looks good here. I can see he overlap of the color, but it was reasonable to assume that the background color is only there to visualize the issue, so, besides the overlap of the bottom grid everything else looks good on my end - https://imgur.com/a/0TQi5mG

Comment: which browser? For me in Chrome it looks as described in my comment above. see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj4NG.png

Comment: @hilmar Firefox. Will test later on chrome and report back.